# Add App To VS project?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, sql-server, visual-studio

Goal:
Create and use android and Iphone app as a complementory to my existing project created in C#.

Problem:
Today, I have a project that use N-tier architecture by using C#, Visual Studio and SQL server. A presentation, business logic and data layer have their own VS project.

I do not want to reinvent the business logic in java and Objective-C.

How should Android and Iphone's app be enable to use VS's business logic and data layer without reinvent the code?

Comment: Umm, you realize that you don't actually use Visual Studio as part of your N-tier architecture, right?  You use C# in your architecture.  Visual Studio is just the tool you used to write the C# code in and compile it.  Its an important distinction.

Comment: I understand from your perspective. In my case, I used VS project as a different distinction of layer.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use `Xamarin`: https://xamarin.com/

> With a C# shared codebase, developers can use Xamarin to write native iOS, Android, and Windows apps with native user interfaces and share code across multiple platforms

As you already have developed your business logic in C#, all you need to do is wrap it in Xamarin Android and IOS projects. Xamarin also offers UI-Design that can be done with Visual Studio, so your original IDE does not change.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Have you tried this Xamarin before?

Comment: I have looked into writing Android and IOS apps with C# myself, and this appeared to be the best option. It removes the need to re-write any logic in java or objective-c; and you can work from your original IDE. The only downfall for me was the price, Xamarin is quite expensive. Seeing as I am just a student~

Comment: How is it about the performance issue between xamarin's app and regular app that is not created by Xamarin?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-benefit-disadvantages-using-121874.S.5848849341191569409). Some people discuss Xamarin.

Comment: Xamarin App is much better than any other cross platform App and Close to native application. But , it is a paid. you can use it only for One month trail and deploy your application only for 24 hrs.